# Python 3.3 : TabError in Print

Tags: python

I want to read file and do some string functions like below.

```
ins = open( "data.txt", "r" )
for line in ins:
category = (line.split("/"))[0]
print (category)
ins.close()
```

However, the error message shows below:

```
File "C:\Python33\parsing_food.py", line 4
print (category)
               ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

How do I solve this?

I want to split string with "/" character and print the first string in the returned array.

Comment: Did you try making sure that your source code only uses either spaces or tabs?

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, You right, I fixed it !!

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all. On this line:

```
print (category)
```

You've indented with a *tab*. Everywhere else you've used a space. Stay consistent and you won't have this error.

In Python, code blocks are denoted using indentation. Spaces are preferred over tabs. You should configure your editor to use four spaces when you press <kbd>tab</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
ins = open( "data.txt", "r" )
for line in ins:
category = (line.split("/"))[0]
print category
ins.close()
```

to:

```
ins = open( "data.txt", "r" )
for line in ins:
    category = (line.split("/"))[0]
    print category
ins.close()
```

In Python - it's all about the indentation and spaces - just like the error says.

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent the lines in the for loop.

```
for line in ins:
    category = (line.split("/"))[0]
    print(category)
```